# Exibir a posição de um determinado valor em um vetor no R

Tags: array, r

Iniciei os estudos em R a pouco tempo e tenho estudado muito essa linguagem. No entanto, estou com dificuldades de como fazer para obter a posição de um vetor, ou seja a ordem em que determinado valor está gravado nesse vetor.

Ex.: > vetor <- c(15, 23, 32, 53, 64)

> vetor
>        [1] 15 23 32 53 64

Como fazer para exibir por exemplo a posição do valor 53, (sei que é a quarta posição)?

Comment: Me desculpem pelo título, é que eu tinha outra pergunta a fazer sobre set.seed e acabei esquecendo de mudar o título!

Comment: Clique em EDITAR e corrija o titulo, se for o caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira forma de obter-se a posição de um determinado elemento de um vetor é usando a função `match` da seguinte maneira `match(c(15, 53), vetor)`. Isso irá retornar a posição dos elementos do vetor que você considera conhecidos.

A segunda forma é usando a função `which` da seguinte maneira `which(vetor %in% c(23, 53))`.

Para fins de conhecimento, caso queira saber o elemento do vetor com base em uma determinada posição, pode-se utilizar o comando `vetor[3]`, onde 3 representa a terceira posição. O resultado será o elemento da terceira posição que neste caso é o 32.

Comment: Muito obrigado Vinicius! ;)